# C + WinAPI: Creating A "Static" Like Class Which Allows Me To Update Caption

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to make a small program in C and Windows API and I need to update some text in a static control.
I have read that changing static's text at runtime is not possible and I have to duplicate the class and make one according to requirement. The problem is, how do I duplicate the class. I am a beginner and below is the current class attributes I have(which is of course, for a window!). What changes are needed for such a control?
Or if it is too much work,should I use a text box(unchangable by user) instead?

```
wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.lpszClassName = TEXT( "Window" );
wc.hInstance     = hInstance ;
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndLogProc;
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
```

Comment: I discovered something. If I add WS_DISABLED to an Edit contorl, it looks like static! And editing its text is not rocket science! So, it is done.

Comment: You can post that as an answer and accept it if it works for you.

Comment: I am a new user and it is asking me to wait 24 hours before answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who told you that it's not possible to change a static window's text? If you use [`SetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx) you can change the contents. It will not display those new contents automatically, but you can force the window to redraw with [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911(v=vs.85).aspx).

P.S. You should be using a class type of "static" for a static control, not "Window". The list of built-in window classes is [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I read that in a tutorial! Well, I didn't know about SetWindowText(I have been into WIN Api for only 5-6 days!). For now, I am using disabled Edit Boxes as they do the same thing. However, I will look into SetWindowText next time. 
Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Ishan Sharma, a disabled edit box is not quite the same. It shows in a different color, and allows the text to be selected. This is especially unfortunate if you're used to using the Tab key to move from one control to the next, as you don't expect to stop at static text.

Comment: Yes, I know it has a different color but did not know the text is selectable. My app does not have much fields, so I will skip the SetWindowText for now.

Comment: @Ishan Sharma: And what tutorial would that be?

Comment: @In Silico Sorry but I do not remember! I have like 20 tabs open about Windows API right now and pinning down exact one would be very hard!